# Why are varactors unspecified at 0V?

Tags: varactor

Specsheets I'm reading tend to specify maximum capacitance at 1V instead of 0V reverse voltage bias.

[NXP BB series](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BB171.pdf) don't show anything below 1V in the tables and 0.5V in the graph.

[Skyworks SMV series](http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/SMV1801_079LF_200915G.pdf) show a table of capacitance versus reverse voltage including 0V, but in the Electrical Specifications table, it still specifies 1V and not 0V.

Why is this? Do they assume that no one wants to bias the diode in the nonlinear region? Is the variance around the maximum capacitance so high that it's not even worth specifying?

Comment: Lets imagine they put in 0V there, then someone complains about not having their 3.3V in there. And then someone wants 3.13V and someone else 5V and then someone 9.17V and so on ... or those people could just look at the graphics, which btw. seems to go down to .5V for the NXP one... out of interest, what are you doing with them that you need the capacitance at 0V? I mean, if you have 0V across it, you can hardly use that capacitance for anything, can you?

Comment: It's difficult to say whether or not I can use that capacitance for anything if I don't know what the capacitance is.

Comment: Also, saying "0V is just as arbitrary as 9.17V" is clearly not true.

Comment: Say you bias a the diode at 0 V and apply 100 mV signal to it, then the capacitance will change significantly with that signal. Bias it at 1V DC and that 100 mV is only 10 % so less significant, the capacitance is more close to the "1 V DC" value. In practice it is almost never an issue to bias a varactor as you can use an AC coupling capacitor to separate the circuit and the DC biasing. Also I think that any varactor behaves as a very bad capacitor when biased at 0 V.

Comment: Bad in what way? Poor Q / high leakage?

Comment: Yes probably poor Q as there needs to be a gap between the depletion layers to form a proper capacitor. You'd have to read up on PN junctions and reverse biasing capacitance to fully understand. I don't recall the full explanation at this moment.

Comment: I don't see where anyone ever said that its the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because varactors are *diodes*.  The special thing about a varactor diode is that it is deliberately designed to harness how the depletion region size grows and shrinks with reverse applied voltage.  That changes the capacitance between the terminals.  You apply a DC reverse voltage to set the capacitance, then use that with a small AC signal.  The DC bias can change, which changes the capacitance.

However, all this stops working if the diode becomes forward biased.  This means the DC bias plus the peaks of the AC signal must still be negative.  To use a varactor as intended, you always need some negative DC bias.  It's also good to stay out of the region right at 0 bias because it's less linear and small changes in voltage have a larger effect.  As a result, nobody cares what the diode does with less than -1 V bias, since you don't want to use it that way.

Comment: While they are characterized at -0.5 and -1 V they can be used into the region above this. If you were designing an LC oscillator the signal level would be high, and modulation of the capacitance value would be a valid concern. However when used where signal levels are very low (such as in aerial tuned circuits) the modulation is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

From application perspective, main use of varactor is as a variable capacitor, preferably a linear one with control voltage. The capacitance at -1-V point is a good single-value characterization of the varactor abilities as a capacitor, as a high-pint in capacitance curve/line. Below -1 V the curve flattens out and isn't much useful.
[image]
Working range is shown, with reference (spec) point circled.